# What is color of NavigationBar in Jetpack Compose in Material color scheme?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigationbar, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material-you

When I`m trying to force `NavigationBar` to be `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface` color(see [Material 3 Guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs)), background color of app and color of `NavigationBar` differs. Example: color of `NavigationBar` is `#f1edf7` but background color is `#fffbfe`. Background app color is `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface` too.

[image: NavigationBar]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a thing named `tonalElevation` in material design 3. Same "base" color is different at different tonal elevation. Surface by default has tonal elevation 0dp, which means that background color is used as is. `NavigationBar` has tonal elevation 3dp, which changes the color slightly. If you want to force `NavigationBar` to be exactly surface color, change its tonal elevation to 0.

See this: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/071c483c7223af673a5c0145e2fee7b0c94af1fd:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/ColorScheme.kt;l=501

Answer (score 10):

The proper way to replicate the color of the `NavigationBar` is to use the same function used behind the scenes to calculate it:

```
MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp)
```

The default `ElevationToken` used for `NavigationBar` is `Level2`, equivalent to 3dp.
If you set a custom different elevation for your `NavigationBar`, set it too in this function and the color will be the same for both.

Comment: worked great for me, thanks. However, how do you know that `NavigationBar` is Level 2? Where is this documented by google?

Comment: If you access NavigationBar code, you will see the tonalElevation default value is NavigationBarDefaults.Elevation. There, the Elevation value is NavigationBarTokens.ContainerElevation. And inside that you find the value is ElevationTokens.Level2. I don't know if it is properly documented, found it by going down the classes.

Comment: thank you, like the technical way :-) Meanwhile I also found documentation: https://m3.material.io/styles/elevation/tokens#df721a00-888e-4c5e-bfe1-5d905f167aaa

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing the elevation of the navigation bar, you could also calculate the color as it would be done within the material component:

```
activity.window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = 0.08f).compositeOver(colorScheme.surface.copy()).toArgb()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a really helpful answer on simulating tonal elevation for the navigation bar.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the same color e.g White in the NavigationBar try this:

Container color

```
NavigationBar(
        containerColor = Color.White
)
```

No color change on tap

```
NavigationBar(
        contentColor = Color.White
)
```

Selected/Unselected icon, selectedText, Indicator:

```
NavigationBarItem(
       colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
          selectedIconColor = Color.Green,
          unselectedIconColor = Color.Gray,
          selectedTextColor = Color.Transparent,
          indicatorColor = Color.White
       )
)
```

You can also change the selectedIconColor and unselectedIconColor colors above to Color.Transparent and control the color in the NavigationBarItem, but you need some logic to control selected/unselected color for icon and/or label.

e.g

```
NavigationBarItem(
      label = {
         Text(
            text = "Tab A",
            color = Color.White // selected/unselected color logic here
         )
      },
     icon = {
       Icon(
          painter = painterResource(id = imageId),
          contentDescription = destItem.destination.route,
          tint = Color.Green // selected/unselected color logic here,
       )         
     },
 )
```

Visit link below for more information about the Navigation bar structure in material3
https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the NavigationBar color by using its `containerColor` property. Just set it to `Color.Transparent` to get the same color your background has.

```
NavigationBar(
  containerColor = Color.Transparent
) {
  ...
}
```